# Появляются лишние li , при выводе

Tags: html, javascript, css, bootstrap

Всем привет, вот такая проблемка с popover от bootstrap.
В приведенном ниже коде, при выводе за каждым `li` следует пустой `li`, подскажите почему или как исправить ?

```
$('[rel=popmenu]').popover({
            placement:'bottom',
            html:'true',
            content: '<div class="pop_menu">'+
                      '<ul class="pop_menu_first">'+
                        '<li><a href="#" class="active">Мне повезёт</a><li>'+
                        '<li><a href="#">Все</a><li>'+
                      '</ul> '+
                      '<ul class="pop_menu_second">'+
                        '<li><a href="#">Арт</a><li>'+
                        '<li><a href="#">Танцы</a><li>'+
                        '<li><a href="#">Дизайн</a><li>'+
                        '<li><a href="#">Мода</a><li>'+
                        '<li><a href="#">Кинематограф</a><li>'+
                        '<li><a href="#">Музыка</a><li>'+
                        '<li><a href="#">Спорт</a><li>'+
                        '<li><a href="#">Театр</a><li>'+
                        '<li><a href="#">Кулинария</a><li>'+
                        '<li><a href="#">Реторика</a><li>'+
                        '<li><a href="#">Модельное исскуство</a><li>'+
                        '<li><a href="#">Фото искусство</a><li>'+
                        '<li><a href="#">Литературное искусство</a><li>'+
                      '</ul>'+ 
                      '</div>'
        });
```

Comment: @Лисёнок точно! Спасибо, моя невнимательность. Благодарю. Ужаснейший косяк

Answer (score 6):

Вероятно потому что теги `li` у вас не закрыты.

```
<li><a href="#">Фото искусство</a></li>
```

Answer (score 5):

Вы, вместо того, чтобы закрыть тег **li**, открываете новый.

Исправьте

```
</a><li>
```

На

```
</a></li>
```

Comment: Спасибо, комментарием выше уже указали на мою невнимательность)

Answer (score 0):

Не хочу начинать споры по поводу использования инструментария вместо личной внимательности. Но я в своем редакторе использую маленький плагин, который подсветит тег, если я все же повторю вашу ошибку.

Comment: Использую Netbeans, в обычных случаях не закрытый тэг бы подсветился, но тут он как строка JavaScript поэтом и не подсветился) А я допустил нелепую ошибку)